# Preventing src from being changed

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to fix an image src set by a javascript function and returned to a HTML tag.

I have a set of array objects that includes, amongst other details, the location of an image for each object:

```
Person[1]= {
Image:"Adam.jpg",
Name:"Adam"
};
```

I then have a function that is designed to extract the relevant image dependent upon an index sent to it.

```
function SetImage(DeskNo)
{
 document.getElementById("DeskImage").src=Person[1].Image
}
```

This is where I run into problems.  The block:

```
<div class="img>
<script>
SetImage(1);
</script>

<img id="DeskImage" width="30" height="30">
```

doesn't display anything, but does appear to very briefly flash up an image on loading before clearing it.

This block is repeated, but with an index of 2 and then 3 etc.  The idea is that the function can be used to extract and return the image, and display several of them on screen at the same time.

A similar function triggered by 'onmouseover' seems to work successfully, which makes me wonder if the image is being overwritten somewhere, which brings me to my question title.  Is it possible to set an src via an element id (in this case 'DeskImage') or otherwise and fix it after the image has been set the first time, even if the src that id points to changes?

I wondered if a direct return of the src from the function may be possible, or alternatively if the index can be automatically appended to the id, however I couldn't identify anything in my searches.

If anyone has any ideas they would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a jsfidle

Comment: Do you use the same id for all of your images?

Comment: #NotAnAnswer `<div class="img>`, you forgot the closing double quote here.

Comment: What you want to achieve is still unclear to me. It sounds like you want to run a loop over all elements of `Person[]` array to set the `src` of the image according to it. But then your question says that you don't want the `src` to change, so how is it possible to switch images in one image tag without changing its `src`. It would be easier to understand your question if you provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Deepak Kamat.  The idea is that each index of Person[] points to a different image.  So at a particular location on the page, SetImage() is passed an index and sets an src according to it.  Then somewhere else on the page calls SetImage() with a different index, to set a different image somewhere else.  But the image displayed on the first call to SetImage() shouldn't change when the function is called again somewhere else on the page.  After an image is displayed in a location it should not change until a refresh.  I'm sorry, I don't know what a jsfiddle is, but will investigate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are calling `SetImage` *before* `DeskImage` exists.  You need to wait until the page is ready before calling your script.

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    SetImage(1);
};
</script>

<img id="DeskImage" width="30" height="30">
```